# Composer update failure

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I understand there has been a number of solutions provided for this question but I can't seem to find an answer.After running `composer update` I am getting this error  [Problem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOjq8.png). What could be the issue? Here is the "required" section for the composer.json file.

`"require": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.8",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "~0.8",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.3",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "~1.4",
        "illuminate/support": "^6.12",
        "intervention/image": "~2.4",
        "laracasts/utilities": "~2.1",
        "laravel/framework": "~5.6",
        "laravel/socialite": "~3.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1",
        "maxhoffmann/parsedown-laravel": "dev-master",
        "mcamara/laravel-localization": "~1.2",
        "mews/purifier": "^2.1",
        "milon/barcode": "~5.3",
        "nitmedia/wkhtml2pdf": "dev-master",
        "omnipay/common": "~3",
        "omnipay/dummy": "~3",
        "omnipay/paypal": "~3",
        "omnipay/stripe": "3.1",
        "php-http/curl-client": "^1.7",
        "php-http/message": "^1.6",
        "predis/predis": "~1.1",
        "vinelab/http": "~1.5",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^6.43",
        "paynow/php-sdk": "^1.0",
        "berzel/paynow-php": "^1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "7.3.*",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "5.0.*",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "1.8.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~3.0"
    },`

Comment: This is normally because the version of a package or one of its dependencies you are requiring is higher than that of another package that is required. For example you could be requesting iluminate/support v6 but laracasts/utilities is requiring v5 or the same package

Comment: Do not share links to images of an error. Links can go down. A text description of the error is better. Also can you share your composer.json file?

Comment: laravelcollective/html requires illuminate support v6 - so you need to require an older version that requires illuminate support v5. There may be more that require v6 but that is the one that stuck out.

Answer (score 0):

One or many of your packages are looking for a different version of another / sub package.  Not only does Laravel itself depend on a whole slew of different 3rd party packages, so do the packages you install.  Keeping up to date on all of them is challenging.

If you look at the error reported:

> Laracasts/utilities 2.1 requires illuminate/support ~5.0

It is telling you that this particular package you are trying to install (**Laracasts utils**) needs a **v5** from **illuminate/support**.  Most likely, if you are working with Laravel V6, you thus are likely pulling in an **illuminate/support** package of a different version than required.

**Solution:**

Either find an updated **Laracast** package that will accept a newer version of **illuminate/support**, or reduce Laravel to V5 (which will pull in an older version of support).  Former is preferable :)

Comment: Unless I am mistaken the composer.json file indicates I am using V5.6 of laravel framework.

Comment: It could be the dependency of another package, it would be helpful if you posted the required dependencies part of your composer.json file as part of the question.

Comment: I just added the composer.json file.

Comment: laravelcollective/html requires illuminate support v6 - so you need to require an older version that requires illuminate support v5.  There may be more that require v6 but that is the one that stuck out.

Comment: Yep.  You'll need to review all your packages (sometimes by reviewing the docs for dependencies, sometimes by just running composer to see what errors show up) to get this right.  More packages = more dependencies = more potential for breaking = more cost to devs.  Another path is to try to reduce your packages where possible & write your own internal code.  In the end it might save a bit of headaches and cost as versions change.

Comment: Okay.Thank you guys,let me try it out.